# How do we analyse cluster features in Python to formulate a pattern for anomaly detection?

Tags: python, networking, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I am working on ISCX Dataset 2012 to study anomaly detection. I have applied K-means clustering using Weka Libraries for Python.

Though it prints the cluster information,

1. it doesn't allow me to save cluster features (average for each feature) in some variable,
2. nor does it give me any information about which tuple goes in which cluster.

I also searched through other libraries to perform clustering, but couldn't find a solution. Is there any alternative to perform a post-cluster formation analysis?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question and avoid being dismissed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I never used weka library, although I assume there is a way in weka. If you are willing to use [sklearn k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), it is very easy to use.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a dataset
ds = np.random.random((50, 2))
ds_anomaly = np.asarray([[-1,1], [1,-1]])
ds = np.concatenate((ds,ds_anomaly))
```

Once kmeans fit is called, your cluster centers (2 in this case) can be retrieved from kmeans.cluster_centers_. And labels assigned to dataset can be retrieved from kmeans.labels_.

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(ds)

# appropriate cluster labels of points in ds
data_labels = kmeans.labels_
# coordinates of cluster centers
cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

colors = ['b', 'g']
plt.scatter(ds[:, 0], ds[:, 1],
                        c=[colors[i] for i in data_labels], s=1)
plt.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 0], cluster_centers[:, 1], color = "k")
plt.show()
```

You can either plot the results and find the anomalies yourself;
[image]

Or you can do some kind of data analysis and get the anomalies. Following is a very basic example where it uses [np.percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to find different values. You can change anomalies function (which should if you want good results) into a more complex function.

```
def anomalies(data):
    perc = np.percentile(data, 99)
    return data[np.where(data>perc)[0]]

for idx, c in enumerate(kmeans.cluster_centers_):
    c_anomaly = anomalies(ds[np.where(kmeans.labels_==idx)])
    print(c_anomaly)
    plt.scatter(c_anomaly[:, 0], c_anomaly[:, 1], c="r", marker="o")

plt.show()
```

And the result is the `([[-1, 1], [1, -1]])` values as expected;
[image]

---

**Disclaimer:** Depending on the initialization, your cluster centers may endup near your anomalies. I'd suggest you perform anomaly detection with another algorithm or to be careful when picking up k value and cluster initialization pattern.